# Can I say "a short summary" or just "summary"?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

Can I use this expression? I use Grammarly app on a regular basis, and the phrase was marked as a tautology...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether to avoid tautology or not is your personal preference but "**summary**" by definition is "*a brief statement or restatement of main points, especially as a conclusion to a work*". You could surely say "*brief/short/compact/condensed summary*" but that would be buttered butter.

Better to use words like "*description*", "*note*", "*article*", or possibly "*extract*" with such adjectives. Notice that adjectives like "**concise**" or "**succinct**" can work with "**summary**" since besides "**briefness**" they mean "*being comprehensive*" or otherwise "*giving a lot of information clearly*".

Answer (score 1):

Tautology is not, strictly, a grammatical error, but an *unnecessary usage* of a word which can count as a fault in style.

*Summary* in itself is a *Short overview* of a story. Therefore, *Short* as an adjective to this word would be useless. Saying just *Summary* would make it clear.

Hence, one should avoid using such.